# Cloud via cloudKit OR Parse scheme data

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud, cloudkit

I'm new to the cloud, The requirement is something like *BaaS*.

the scheme has been set it up in the cloudKit dashboard or Parse - In the Public database is accessible for all(as announced in the doc), So Can I Use the Cloud via cloudKit Or Parse cloud to ***keep data things separately according to the Authentication*** ?

**In Simple:**

> Can I use the cloud via cloudKit, as a default scheme but the
>   data(scheme data) should be different according to the User(based on
>   authentication)

For Ex:

***An App which has the default backend scheme (database), but the users(App owners) are different (keep the data and retrieval data according to their own), How can i acheive this? IS this is possible as with cloud based App??***

Answer (score 1):

With CloudKit you can have a private and a public database each having it's own structure. Records in the private database can only be read by the user itself. The public database is accessible to everyone. Just have a look at CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase and the .privateCloudDatabase.

Comment: Edwin - you seem very knowledgeable about CloudKit. I understand that you cannot really create a log-in/username system with CK (because you are limited to auth'ing) - so if you had an app that required usernames, how could you implement this with CK as your backend? Would it make sense to even try this?

Comment: When writing data to CloudKit, you have to be loged in into iCloud. When you are loged in to iCloud, you will have a unique ID that could be used as a user name. You would not need an extra user ID to identify users. If you want to give a user a nice name, then you could add a users table and add that data in there.

Comment: Thank you Edwin for clarifying